# Custom media uploader not showing library

Tags: uploads, media, library

i am developing a plugin that allows upload an image.

Actually the plugin works *fine* it means, that if you upload an image, the image get set in the database, but, not show the images on the library, so, the user must upload the image all times... thats not good...

I dont know why the library is not showing up the images... can anybody help me?

Wordpress version 3.6.2
No addtional plugins installed

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var custom_uploader;

    $('#upload_image_button').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
        if (custom_uploader) {
            custom_uploader.open();
            return;
        }

        //Extend the wp.media object
        custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Choose Image',
            button: {
                text: 'Choose Image'
            },
            multiple: false
        });

        //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
        custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
            attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            $('#upload_image').val(attachment.url);
        });

        //Open the uploader dialog
        custom_uploader.open();

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Anyone can give me a line?